# Book where a guy is saved by his glow-in-the-dark watch?

Tags: story-identification

A guy ends up in another (possibly parallel) world where there are primitive humanoids living in a barren land. There are also huge single-cell organisms. Because he has a glow-in-the-dark watch which contains some radioactivity, he is able to enter and kill a single-cell organism, thus creating fertile ground for agriculture.

I could swear it was called *Dimension D* but I can't find it by googling that title. I probably read it in the late 70's and I'd say it was fairly new at the time. I would like to confirm the book's title and author.

Comment: Do you have any idea when the book was published?

Comment: I probably read it in the late 70's and I'd say it was fairly new at the time.

Comment: ISFDB offers two possibilities: "Dimension A" by L. P. Davies (1968) and "Dimension X" by Jimmy Guieu (1959). Brief review at https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/l-p-davies-2/dimension-a/ indicates "Dimension A" involves a parallel world, but no mention of watches or giant amoebae.